# stl decomposition in r for daily data shows error only univariate series are allowed

Tags: r

I am trying to decompose a daily time series, however this gives an

> Error 'only univariate series are allowed'

When I have clearly converted the daily data in to time series using the ts function.  How can I fix this?

I have tried solutions from other posts but none has worked for me. My data comprise of `669` observations, where the data spans from `Jan 2017 to March 2019`.

```
SCTB.LV.TS = ts(SCTB_TS[,-1], start = c(2017,6,01), frequency = 365)
SCTB.LV.TS

decomp <- stl(log(SCTB.LV.TS), s.window = 'Periodic')
```

Before converting the data frame to time series the data looks like below

```
Date    Count
6/1/2017    329
6/2/2017    284
6/3/2017    429
6/4/2017    454
6/5/2017    362
6/6/2017    334
6/7/2017    369
6/8/2017    319
6/9/2017    349
6/10/2017   373
6/11/2017   456
6/12/2017   344
```

Comment: It's `"periodic"` not `"Periodic"`. This is working as expected: `stl(log(AirPassengers), s.window = "periodic")`

Comment: I don't think this is a version problem, but you should add your `sessionInfo()` here, with a reproducible complete example. Try first using classical available `ts` like `AirPassengers`.

Comment: 669 observations and daily sampling from Jan 2017 to March 2019 doesn't add up, there's about a four month deficit. Do you have missing data? No sampling during holidays? 669 observations sampled regularly at a frequency of 365 still span less than two periods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time series and stl in R: Error only univariate series are allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492155/time-series-and-stl-in-r-error-only-univariate-series-are-allowed)

Answer (score 0):

I get no complaints of 'only univariate series are allowed', only about too few periods, which is understandable.

```
SCTB_TS <- read.table(text="
    Date      Count
    6/1/2017    329
    6/2/2017    284
    6/3/2017    429
    6/4/2017    454
    6/5/2017    362
    6/6/2017    334
    6/7/2017    369
    6/8/2017    319
    6/9/2017    349
    6/10/2017   373
    6/11/2017   456
    6/12/2017   344", header=TRUE)

# your argument to start didn't make sense, so I changed it
SCTB.LV.TS <- ts(SCTB_TS[,-1], start=c(2017, 1), frequency=365)
SCTB.LV.TS

decomp <- stl(log(SCTB.LV.TS), s.window="periodic")
```

> Error in stl(log(SCTB.LV.TS), s.window = "periodic") :    series is
>   not periodic or has less than two periods

Which again is understandable. How can you do seasonal decomposition when you only have 12/365 period to work with?

Comment: I have 669 observations, where the data spans from June 2018 to March 2019, which I have stated in the question. i have only shared a sample of the data.  I tried changing the code for the ts function which you shared but still get the same error.

Comment: @Gun: June 2018 to March 2019 is still less than one period, let alone two.

Comment: my mistake its from Jan 2017 to March 2019. I have typed this wrong in the question

Comment: @Gun: I think it's time for a reproducible example. Create some dummy data that produce the error, but can also be easily shared.